# Error in Code? [C]

Tags: c

I'm stuck in an infinite loop, for some reason the program doesn't terminate when `\n` is entered. Also the point of the code is to reverse the input, but I'm trying to do it using a pointer instead of an integer to keep track of the position in the array.

```
#define MSG_LENGTH 80

int main(void)
{
    char msg[MSG_LENGTH], *p;

    printf("Enter a message: ");

    for (p = msg; p < &msg[MSG_LENGTH];)
    {
        *p++ = getchar();

        if (*p == '\n')
            break;
    }

    printf("Reversal is: ");

    for (p--; p >= msg;)
        putchar(*p--);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `fgets(nsg, MSG_LENGTH, stdin)` to read the string

Comment: @MohitJain I'm just reading about strings now, so I wouldnt have been able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (p = msg; p < &msg[MSG_LENGTH];)
{
    *p++ = getchar(); <-- Getting character in *p and incrementing p

    if (*p == '\n')   <-- Checking value of next character, not the one just read
        break;
}
```

Possible correction:

```
for (p = msg; p < &msg[MSG_LENGTH]; p+=sizeof(char))
{
    *p = getchar();

    if (*p == '\n')
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#define MSG_LENGTH 80

int main(void)
{
    char msg[MSG_LENGTH], *p;

    printf("Enter a message: ");

    for (p = msg; p < &msg[MSG_LENGTH];)
    {
        *p = getchar();
        if (*p == '\n')
            break;
        p++;
    }

    printf("Reversal is: ");

    for (p--; p >= msg;)
        putchar(*p--);

    return 0;

}
```

You were incrementing the `p` pointer before the `break` condition. So, even if `*p` was containing `'\n'`, the check was being made after incrementing the pointer location.